# Ckeditor "c[a] is undefined" in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Originally docs say that you need to add

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

to index.html (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor). 
The problem is that I cannot have external dependencies in the project.

As a next step I tried to add

```
 <script src="../node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

but this will not work after ng build --prod (using nginx)

As a last step I tried to add "node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
to angular.json scripts like below:

```
 "scripts": [
             //some other scripts,
              "node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
            ]
```

part but now I got the

> "ERROR TypeError: "c[a] is undefined" in browser's console.

The depependencies versions are:
ckeditor: ^4.9.2  and     ng2-ckeditor: ^1.2.1

What is the proper way to include ckeditor.js without needing to call cdn.ckeditor.com?

Comment: Full instructions for integration with Angular are.on the project's website at https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: I am not using ckeditor5

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the problem by updating editor to version 5. Than one doesn't require the script to be loaded